# Increment array up to max items

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, loops

I've written this code. It rotates two divs like a card flip using css transform every 1000ms and displays new text in the div, which is drawn from an array. It runs infinitely.

But once the array reaches its end I get an 'undefined' value because the i++ is incrementing on the final array item. I have been going crazy trying to figure out how to prevent that. Any help?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/warpigs666/pen/OJpBKdy

```
    <style>
        #flip-card {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        #flip-card-inner {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transition: transform 0.6s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }
        #textDiv1 {
            background-color: lightblue;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #textDiv2 {
            background-color: lightcoral;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            transform: rotateX(180deg);
        }
    </style>

<body>
    
    <div id="flip-card">
        <div id="flip-card-inner">
            <div id="textDiv1">
                one
            </div>
            <div id="textDiv2">
                set via script
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <script>
        var flipCard = document.getElementById('flip-card');
        var flipCardInner = document.getElementById('flip-card-inner');
        var textDiv1 = document.getElementById('textDiv1');
        var textDiv2 = document.getElementById('textDiv2');
        var wordArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

        var i = 1;

        function flipText(){   
            textDiv2.innerHTML = wordArray[i];
            flipCardInner.style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
            
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    textDiv1.innerHTML = wordArray[i++];
                    flipCardInner.style.transform = "rotateX(360deg)";
                }, 1000
            );
            
            if (i<wordArray.length){
                i++;
            }
                else {i=0;}
        }
        
            var flipIt = setInterval(flipText, 2000);
        
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you really need the `wordArray[i++]`? It might be the reason why it gets overly incremented. If you need to access the i + 1 member of your current array element, put `wordArray[i + 1]` instead.

Comment: I was answering, but then realised your question needs more context. Can you turn your code into a runnable snippet and more clearly explain what the desired behaviour is?

Comment: Take a look at the last section of my updated answer - I wonder if that's the kind of thing you're looking for - an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what you're envisioning with i+1 but that doesn't work at all, I thought it might too, but it still throws an undefined and also causes other problems. I've updated my question and I'll turn the code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: I added a codepen link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `setInterval`

```js
var flipCard = document.getElementById('flip-card');
let flipCardInner = document.getElementById('flip-card-inner');
let textDiv1 = document.getElementById('textDiv1');
let textDiv2 = document.getElementById('textDiv2');
let wordArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

let i = 0;
let timerVal = 1000;

function getI(i) {
  if (i < wordArray.length - 1) return i + 1;
  else return 0;
}
let ctr = 1,
  useDiv; // ctr and useDiv will help to toggle between divs in our loop and also increment the transform number

textDiv1.innerHTML = wordArray[i]; // initialize 

function flipText() {
  i = getI(i);
  useDiv = (useDiv == textDiv2) ? textDiv1 : textDiv2;
  useDiv.innerHTML = wordArray[i];
  flipCardInner.style.transform = "rotateX(" + (ctr * 180) + "deg)";
  ctr++;
}

let interval
window.onload = function() {
  // we'll still delay the beginning of the infinite loop, but then we set it to an interval, so it runs forever.
  // if you need to stop it in your code, just use clearInterval(interval)
  setTimeout(() => {
    interval = setInterval(() => flipText(), timerVal);
  }, timerVal);
}
```

```css
#flip-card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  perspective: 100px;
}

#flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#textDiv1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

#textDiv2 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="flip-card">
  <div id="flip-card-inner">
    <div id="textDiv1">

    </div>
    <div id="textDiv2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still prints undefined.

Comment: Thanks. i starts at 1 because the div is already populated with 0 in the html code itself. I tried your code but it doesn't work for me at all. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ah yes, very interesting thank you! I'll examine it. It starts on 'three' for me though I wonder why that is...

Comment: I had the i set to 1, when I set it to 0 now it starts on "two", but I think it's due to a delay in populating the div. Could I bother you to write the conditional ternary operator as an if/else statement? I am trying but I can't figure out why it won't work as an if/else statement. I tried if(i < wordArray.length-1){i + 1;} else{i=0;} but that just causes everything to print twice.

Comment: Updated. Whenever i am duplicating code, I try not to, so moved that to a little helper function `getI` - also made the timer a variable and prepopulated the div with the first word. So that it didn't start right away, I added a `timeout` in `window.onload`

Comment: Last question (hopefully), the div is rotating in a weird way. If you add 'perspective: 100px;' to the #flip-card css you can see what I mean. Any idea what might be causing that? It functions as normal for one and two, but then it reverses for three. Ideally it should continue rolling over. Currently it goes roll, roll, reverse roll, roll, reverse roll, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I totally refactored it. It didn't make sense the way it was set up. This is a job for setInterval - I commented my code, should make it alot easier for you

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was aiming for! Thank you! This is extremely helpful. I have so many gaps in my coding knowledge this is extremely useful to see your thought process.

Comment: On the chance that you happen to know the solution, I'm now trying to add translateY to the transform, my ultimate goal is to have it look like it's rotating, not flipping, such as in the codepen below. Now I keep getting weird skewing when I try to add it though. No pressure though just thought I'd ask https://codepen.io/warpigs666/pen/vYxQejL

Comment: @epignosis567 - not off the top of my head, but usually I have to get in and play with it first. If you make a new question for this, let me know

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as follows, you are incrementing i twice, when it should just be one time:

```
 function() {
                    textDiv1.innerHTML = wordArray[i++]; ==> Here 
                    flipCardInner.style.transform = "rotateX(360deg)";
                }, 1000
            );
            
            if (i<wordArray.length){
                i++;  ==> And here 
            }
                else {i=0;}
        }
```

remove the increment on wordArray[i++], should not give you error.

Also make it i < wordArray.length -1

Comment: Now it prints 'three',' four', 'five' and 'undefined' twice.

Comment: Also make it i < wordArray.length -1

Comment: Still prints 'undefined'

Comment: Thanks, but this answer has multiple problems. I had already tried it. I'm glad to see so many people giving wrong answers I've been going crazy trying to figure out a simple way of editing my code to do what I'm asking ;) hopefully someone is able to figure something out.

Comment: I have created half solution when it prints all nos without undefined but prints five twice from 2nd round onwards. Let me know if u want it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the ideal way of this job but sticking to your context perhaps like this;

```js
var flipCard      = document.getElementById('flip-card'),
    flipCardInner = document.getElementById('flip-card-inner'),
    textDiv1      = document.getElementById('textDiv1'),
    textDiv2      = document.getElementById('textDiv2'),
    wordArray     = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    i             = 0;

function flipText(){   
  textDiv2.innerHTML = wordArray[++i % wordArray.length];
  flipCardInner.style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
                
  setTimeout(function(){
               textDiv1.innerHTML = wordArray[++i % wordArray.length];
               flipCardInner.style.transform = "rotateX(360deg)";
             }, 1000);
}
            
var flipIt = setInterval(flipText, 2000);
```

```css
#flip-card { width: 100px;
             height: 50px;
           }
#flip-card-inner { position: relative;
                   width: 100%;
                   height: 100%;
                   transition: transform 0.6s;
                   transform-style: preserve-3d;
                 }
#textDiv1 { background-color: lightblue;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            text-align: center;
          }

#textDiv2 { background-color: lightcoral;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            transform: rotateX(180deg);
          }
```

```html
<div id="flip-card">
  <div id="flip-card-inner">
    <div id="textDiv1">
      one
    </div>
    <div id="textDiv2">
      set via script
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```